# Query fails to register upon a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is a plain and simple issue of which I can't figure out what the issue really is. Basically what I've got is a simple query to register a function every time *x* is clicked on, however, the `.click` query is never registered for unknown reasons.

```
$(".char-outfit-list .cell").click(function() { // register ever click to a cell
  $(".char-outfit img").attr("src",
    $("img", this).attr("src")  // set the main image to the cell image source
   );
});
```

The cells are appended dynamically by the script as well:

```
$(".char-outfit-list").append('<div class="cell"><img src="/assets/images/skins/' + id + '.png"></div>');
```

Comment: Do the elements already exist at the time your first code snippet get's executed? If not, the selector will return an empty result set and no click listeners will be registered.

Comment: The elements are added up whenever a `<select>` option has been changed (the list element is cleared out, then they are appended again if its data information is met up with the `<select>` option. So the first snippet is executed before the cells exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is with how the click handler works. Because `.click` runs at the time you execute it, you might not actually be hooking to anything.

You should stick to doing everything in jQuery:

```
let img = $('<img />').attr('src', `/assets/images/skins/${id}.png`);
// Create the cell, AND attach the handler
// $('<div class="cell" />') also works here
let cell = $('<div />')
  .addClass('cell')
  .append(img)
  .click(function() { // register ever click to a cell
    $(".char-outfit img").attr("src",
      $("img", this).attr("src")  // set the main image to the cell image source
    );
  });
// Append the cell with the attached handler
$(".char-outfit-list").append(cell);
```

Or optionally, add a listener to the `.char-outfit-list` div (This is more performant, because you're only attaching one handler, and you only need to do this once!):

```
$(".char-outfit-list").on('click', '.cell', function() { // register ever click to a cell
  $(".char-outfit img").attr("src",
    $("img", this).attr("src")  // set the main image to the cell image source
   );
});
```